# Sending Ajax Call When User Exits

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I want to remove user stored data in my database when the user exits the page. A window dialog box will come up asking if the user really wishes to exit the page. Upon confirming to leave, an Ajax call should be sent to PHP confirming the action. Is it possible for PHP to receive the call in time and execute the command? If not, are there any other ways to verify that the Ajax call is sent successfully and the command is executed?

Comment: [window.onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) may be what you want, or possibly [window.navigator.sendBeacon](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon)

Comment: Were none of the given answers useful? 2 of the bigger ones remain *unvoted* and neither one *marked*

Answer (score 0):

You should not use unreliable, hacky and annoying methods. The only events that come close to your needs are [window.onbeforeunload](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onbeforeunload.asp) and [window.unload](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onunload.asp) but popups are usually blocked in those events (hence the *hacky*) and when blocked the remainder code as well.

There is also the issue that closing a tab will fire the events, closing the browser however will skip them and its all dependent if the browser actually supports it.

---

Perhaps use an ajax call every 5 minutes to detect if the page is still running and update a database with that time.
Now with a server cronjob you should select all rows with a `time < now() - 300` and then you should have a list of browsers that recently connected but are not sending any signal anymore.

Or you could save the data in localstorage every 10 seconds so then there is no need to do all this?

Comment: The reason why I'd like to prompt the user is because if they leave, their information will be unsaved. Warning them before they leave, I think, is a good practice.

Comment: Then perhaps continuously store data in the [local storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) and resume when the user returns. Its like when writing an email and its already saved to drafts, without popups.

Comment: I have a custom based CMS with dynamic cloned forms and each form is connected to a page number. Storing the data in local storage might not work, because the form data has to be displayed in the right order

Answer (score 0):

If you need very short-lived data (only relevant while the user is on the page), a database is not the right tool. Databases are designed to store long-lived data.

I suggest you use sessions instead.  Here's [a quick intro](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php).  Basically, sessions allow you to persist data across http requests, but to expire that data after a short while.

Start the session when the user logs in or opens your entry page, and store in `$_SESSION` any data you want to access while the user is on the page.

**entry or login page**

```
<?php
if(session_status()===PHP_SESSION_NONE) session_start();

... work through your script

//store data you'll need later
$_SESSION['username'] = 'Linda';
$_SESSION['age'] = 22;
$_SESSION['expires'] = time()+ 60*15; //expires in 15 minutes
```

The next time the user makes a request, test whether the session is still active.  If so you can get the data from session, and refresh expiration.  If the session has expired, you can destroy the data.

**protected page**

```
<?php
if(session_status()===PHP_SESSION_NONE) session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['expires']) && $_SESSION['expires'] > time()){
    //session is still active. extend expiration time
    $_SESSION['expiration'] = time() + 60*15;

    //retrieve data
    $user = $_SESSION['username'];
    .... run your script

}else{
   //either the session doesn't exist or it has expired because the user
   //left the page or stopped browsing the site

   //destroy the session and redirect the user
   session_destroy();
   header('Location: /login.php');
}
```

Comment: The information that will be stored in the database are long-lived. I have a custom based CMS with dynamic forms and each form is connected to a page number. Storing the data in sessions is not an option, because the sessions would have to be linked. That's why I'd much rather store the information, and if the user decides to exit the page an Ajax call will be made

Answer (score -1):

Try This:

```
<script>
    window.onbeforeunload = function (event) {
        var message = 'Important: Please click on \'Save\' button to leave this page.';
        if (typeof event == 'undefined') {
            event = window.event;
//ajax call here
        }
        if (event) {
            event.returnValue = message;
        }
        return message;
    };
    </script>
```

Comment: Will this work on most browsers and will PHP actually retrieve the Ajax call?